# Python selenium for amazon change quantity purchase with 999 for check stock products

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I wrote this little program is not ending because I don't know how change the drop and down menu with my value 999 if someone can help it will be nice
The 999 is a trick to know the real stock for a product in stock on Amazon
this is my program

```py
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    
url = 'https://www.amazon.fr/Raspberry-Tactile-Ventilateur-Moniteur-320x480/dp/B07WSVS1Q1/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
    
sleep(3)
#click for accept cookies
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="a-autoid-0"]/span').click()
sleep(3)
    
#click add to cart
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="submit.add-to-cart"]/span/input').click()
sleep(3)
#no extra coverage garanty
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="siNoCoverage"]/span').click()
sleep(3)
#back at cart
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="hlb-view-cart"]/span').click()
sleep(7)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="a-autoid-0-announce"]/span[2]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dropdown1_9"]').click()
```

I changed the end of the program with that

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dropdown1_10"]').click()
sleep(7)

input999 = '//*[@id="sc-item-C5bd1271b-b46a-4d6e-901c-b5109e1e4868"]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/span[1]'
input999.send.keys(search_text)
input999.send_keys('999')
```

Now I have the cursor available so I try to insert the value 999 but the console returns an error

```
input999.send.keys(search_text)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'send'
```

I really try to figure out this case and I search tutorial on youtube but nothing talk about this...

Answer (score 1):

```
input999 = '//*[@id="sc-item-C5bd1271b-b46a-4d6e-901c-b5109e1e4868"]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/span[1]' input999.send.keys(search_text)
input999.send_keys('999')
```

Is that exactly what you have written? If so, the error makes sense. You are defining input999 as a string. It should be more like:

```
input999 = find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="sc-item-C5bd1271b-b46a-4d6e-901c-b5109e1e4868"]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/span[1]').send_keys('999')
```

Also, if I'm not mistaken, it is a bad idea to reference *@id="sc-item-C5bd1271b-b46a-4d6e-901c-b5109e1e4868* because it will change if you refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

thank you mr_mooo_cow
Yes I did find the solution and not wrote and answer
now this how looks my programs

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals`
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

#url = "https://www.amazon.fr/nouveau-fire-tv-stick-avec-telecommande-vocale-         alexa-avec-boutons-de-controle-de-la-tv-son-dolby-atmos-modele-2020/dp/B07ZZVRWLK/ref=zg_bs_electronics_home_1?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=TSFMMW1MZXXRW2610ZMG"
url="https://www.amazon.fr/K%C3%A4rcher-Premium-Control-nettoyeur-pression/dp/B0185UN2QA/ref=zg_bs_lawn-garden_2?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1& refRID=R2VMR8R1DN70P49F19QW"
#url = 'https://www.amazon.fr/Raspberry-Tactile-Ventilateur-Moniteur-320x480/dp/B07WSVS1Q1/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)

sleep(3)
#click for accept cookies
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="a-autoid-0"]/span').click()
sleep(3)

#click add to cart
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="submit.add-to-cart"]/span/input').click()
sleep(5)
#no extra coverage garanty
#driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="siNoCoverage"]/span').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="attachSiNoCoverage-announce"]').click()
sleep(3)
#back at cart
#driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="hlb-view-cart"]/span').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="attach-sidesheet-view-cart-button"]   /span/input').click()
sleep(7)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="a-autoid-0-announce"]/span[2]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dropdown1_10"]').click()
sleep(7)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//input[@name="quantityBox"]').send_keys('999')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="a-autoid-1"]').click()
sleep(6)
stock = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="sc-subtotal-label-buybox"]').text
print(stock.replace("Sous-total (", " ").replace("articles):"," "))
with open ('result.txt', 'a') as file:
file.write(stock+'\n')
```

And I changes also  @id="sc-item-C5bd1271b-b46a-4d6e-901c-b5109e1e4868 with the good Xpath. I'm begginer in Python and I try to improve myself in scraping.
Thank you again for your answers :-)